# MySQL GROUP BY condition on ALL rows (not WHERE or HAVING)

Tags: mysql, group-by

I think this is a tough one (only for SQL hardcores) but the problem proposed is simple.
I have a log table that logs connection and disconnection times of users in Unix timestamps:

```
USER_ID  |   CONN_TIME   |   DISC_TIME
1        |   1533742332  |   1533744332
2        |   1533744232  |   1533744337
1        |   1533744132  |   1533754332
3        |   1533714332  |   1533744532
3        |   1533744032  |   1533744532
```

Now, I'd need a way to group rows by 10 minutes intervals and count the number of online users in each interval. I know how to `GROUP BY` `CONN_TIME` or `DISC_TIME` but this way I only get how many users connected or disconnected in a ten minute interval, not how many users were online `(CONN_TIME - DISC_TIME)`.

My current SQL statement is as follows:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(CONN_TIME), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as date, COUNT(*) as hits
FROM Stats
GROUP BY FLOOR(CONN_TIME / 600)
```

As you can see I can only get the hits count which is completely unsatisfactory for showing user's activity. I'd like to know if he was still online in that period.

Comment: Consider using the MOD function, and look into MySQL "at variables" (a non-standard extension) that lets you store state as a query runs. You might even need a "pivot" table, but also remember that there are things you can't do with SQL. You might need a procedural language at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a few hours I think I finally have something that resembles an answer to your problem. However, I have not thoroughly tested it, so I cannot guarantee it is fully functional and exactly as you need it, use at your own risk.

[Here it is as a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f49a/151) and now some explanations of what I did:

First I created two views, the first one generates the numbers from 0 to 16, the second one generates the numbers from 0 to 256. (You could probably inline these views, but I didn't).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL
SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL
SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;
```

Ok, now we can generate the timestamps starting from the lowest `CONN_TIME` to the highest `DISC_TIME`:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL @i MINUTE)) AS result_date
FROM generator_256
CROSS JOIN
  (
     SELECT 
       @i:=-10, 
       @start_date:= FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR((SELECT MIN(CONN_TIME) FROM Stats) / 600) * 600)
  ) AS init
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL@ i: = @i + 10 MINUTE)) 
  BETWEEN(FLOOR((SELECT MIN(CONN_TIME) FROM Stats) / 600) * 600) 
  AND(CEIL((SELECT MAX(DISC_TIME) FROM Stats) / 600) * 600)
```

Then you'll need to join the stats onto it

```
JOIN Stats 
    ON Stats.CONN_TIME = Stats.CONN_TIME # Condition which is always true
    AND time.result_date + 600 > Stats.CONN_TIME # Logon is before end of timespan
    AND time.result_date < Stats.DISC_TIME  # Logoff is after beginning of timespan
```

and group the entire thing by result_date.

I have omitted some parts in this text post, I would suggest looking at the fiddle linked above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: WOW, it took me hours trying to understand the underlying logic. You are an SQL Monster. If I have to be sincere I was convinced NO ONE would solve this. Thank you so much!